# Can't add android platform in cordova 3.3

Tags: android, cordova, addition, platform

I tried to add the android platform by:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

I get that out:

```
    Creating android project...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
    at /Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
    at _rejected (/Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/jannisportmann/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:244:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

I specified the SDK's path in the .bash_profile, is there something more I need to do?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova platform add android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897115/cordova-platform-add-android-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it!! First you have to add android tools and platform tools to your PATH...

So open your user profile ( in terminal type:)

```
nano ~/.profile
PATH=$PATH:/YOUR_ADT_FOLDER/sdk/platform-tools:/YOUR_ADT_FOLDER/sdk/tools
export PATH
```

Save it and type on terminal:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Now try to add your cordova platform, if it not works try to install apache ant. I'm using elementary os, so I opened the software center, searched for ant e install it. After it see if 'ant' is on your terminal and then add your platform.

Comment: can you help for windows?

Comment: I did this and still ge tthe same error. 

export HOME="/Users/rover"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Documents/Dev/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$PATH"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/bin/ant"
#export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"

  $ which ant
/usr/local/bin/ant
  $ ls /usr/local/bin/ant
/usr/local/bin/ant

$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4

$ cordova --version
4.0.0

error is: node_modules/q/q.js:126 throw e;

Comment: @mylord Did you restart your CLI?

Comment: @B.K. I solved that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783594/phonegap-cordova-build-android-node-modules-q-q-js-throw-e

Answer (score 0):

For OSX your path needs to include /Users/yourusername

their example: /Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools 
needs to be: /Users/yourusername/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools

check your path with echo $PATH (use caps, it's case sensitive!)

Answer (score 0):

this is documentation [Phonegab docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android_3a_setup_your_path_environment_variable_on_mac_os) for setup .bash_profile(mac),bashrc(linux), or windows

and my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools
```

visit the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951809/how-to-add-platform-android-cordova-on-mac)

I hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Have you tried with 'sudo'? sometimes I run into permissions issues with the various libraries.