# Error trying to add android platform to Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, npm

I'm running on ubuntu 13.10 and I've installed cordova using npm(if that makes a difference). When I create a project and then try to run `cordova platform add android` I get the following Error:

```
/home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
    at /home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:47:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
Error: /home/user/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova add platform error in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191106/cordova-add-platform-error-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/).

You can do so by running the command
`sudo apt-get install ant`

Another common issue:
The android sdk platform-tools and tools dir both have to be within your $PATH

Your implementation may vary but something along the lines of:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools

source ~/.bash_profile
```

see: [Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

Comment: Self answering your question.